# Recursive method in javascript always returns undefined instead of true,

Tags: javascript

Why does the following method always return undefined? Event though the log in the console says true?

```
var x = [1,2,3,4,5];
var y = 9;


function addUp (x, y) {
  for (var i=0, j=1; j < x.length; j++) {
    if (x[i] + x[j] === y) {
      console.log("in here result should be true");
      var result = true;
      break;
    }
   }

  console.log("len", x.length, "result",result);
  if ((!result) && (x.length > 2)) {
    console.log("recursively calling");
    addUp(x.slice(i+1, x.length), y)
  } else if(result) {
    console.log("in the if why doesn't this return true?")
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

addUp(x,y);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to **return** the result of recursive calls:

```
return addUp(x.slice(i+1, x.length), y)
```

instead of just:

```
addUp(x.slice(i+1, x.length), y)
```

Comment: doh! indeed totaly missed it, thanks @shomz! Will mark the question as correct in 5 minutes once stackoverflow allows me.

Comment: You're welcome, it happens. :) There's one thing I learned that helped me avoid this mistake: when writing recursive functions, start by writing the base case (which could be something like `if (x.length <= 2) return !!result;` in your case) and the recursive case (`return addUp...`) and then work on the code body.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your first `if` statement

```
console.log("len", x.length, "result",result);
  if ((!result) && (x.length > 2)) {
    console.log("recursively calling");
    addUp(x.slice(i+1, x.length), y)
  } else if(result) {
    console.log("in the if why doesn't this return true?")
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
```

You will see that the `if ((!result) && (x.length > 2)) {` does not return anything. Therefore if this match is found the following next two else statements will not be executed.

You should provide either a return statement in the first if statement or put a final return at the end of the method.